# How to remove style attribute in WordPress RSS output?

Tags: functions, themes, rss

I have tested my RSS using the W3C Feed Validator but it is outputting an error to fix: `style attribute contains potentially dangerous content: max-width`

How can I fix this error and **remove style attribute**?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Comment: Thanks, still looking for an answer.

Comment: I googled the error and found a WordPress forum discussion. The suggestion that worked was to try to figure out which plugin or theme is adding inline CSS in a div. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fix-new-rss-wordpress-feed-error/